# why does this code throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Eventually I got the answer, but it puzzled me for a while.

Why does the following code throws NullPointerException when run?

```
import java.util.*;

class WhyNullPointerException {
    public static void main( String [] args ){
       // Create a map
        Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        // Get the previous value, obviously null.
        Integer a = m.get( "oscar" );
        // If a is null put 1, else increase a
        int p = a == null ? 
            m.put( "oscar", 1) : 
            m.put( "oscar", a++ ); // Stacktrace reports Npe in this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if after a while no one posts the answer then it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.

Comment: In case this is a common pattern in your software, you might look into ApacheCommons DefaultedMap to decorate the map to return 1 automatically.. http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/DefaultedMap.html

Comment: @I82Much Thanks for the link. No, actually I was creating a blog entry about closures in java 7 :P  This is it: ( in Spanish though ) http://bit.ly/ClosuresEnJavaMexico

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because [`m.put`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) returns `null` (which indicates that there's no "previous" value) while you're trying to assign it to `int`. Replace `int p` by `Integer p` and it will work.

This is specified in [JLS 5.1.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190699):

> #### [5.1.8 Unboxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190699)
>
> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> - If *r* is `null`, unboxing conversion throws a `NullPointerException`

---

Unrelated to the problem, just a side suggestion with [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in mind, consider writing it so:

```
    Integer p = m.put("oscar", a == null ? 1 : a++);
```

It's a bit more readable :)

Comment: Does this have something to do with auto boxing?

Comment: @Johannes: Indeed it does. The Integer is auto-unboxed into an int - if the Integer happens to be null, the unboxing throws.

Comment: @Johannes: Indeed, `null` cannot be unboxed to a primitive, it will throw NPE. See also [Autoboxing guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Actually the stacktrace is missleading, because it makes you think the problem is in `a++`  but try substituting with any number , ie `put( "oscar", /*a++*/ 4`) for instance, and the line returned by the Npe would be where `put("oscar",1)` instead.  I'm not sure why does it report it in that line.

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning `int p` to the return value of `m.put()`.  But `put()` returns `null` in this situation, and you can't assign an `int` to `null`.

From the Javadocs for `HashMap.put()`:

> **Returns:**
>       previous value associated with specified key, or null if there was no
>   mapping for key.