# Java NPE in ternary operator with autoboxing?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I ran across a very weird NPE this morning, and reduced it to a simple example. Is this a JVM bug or correct behavior?

```
public class Test1 {
    class Item {
        Integer id = null;
        public Integer getId() {return id;}
    }   
    public Integer f() {
        Item item = new Item();
        // this works:
        //return item == null ? new Integer(1) : item.getId();

        // NPE??
        return item == null ? 1 : item.getId();
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        System.out.println("id is: " + String.valueOf(t.f()));
    }   
}
```

Output from compile and run:

```
$ javac Test1.java 
$ java Test1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Test1.f(Test1.java:12)
at Test1.main(Test1.java:16)
$
```

Comment: pst use `Integer.valueOf(1)` instead of `new Integer(1)`

Comment: that'a a good catch with autoboxing.  This is why popular best practices recommend to use primitive type over wrapper.

Comment: Very similar to [strange Java NullPointerException with autoboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265948/strange-java-nullpointerexception-with-autoboxing)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The type of the expression `item == null ? 1 : item.getId()` is `int` not `Integer`.  Therefore, Java needs to auto-unbox your `Integer` to an `int` (causing the `NullPointerException`).  Then it auto-boxes the result  back to an `Integer` (well it *would* if not for the `NullPointerException`) to return from the method.

On the other hand, the expression `item == null ? new Integer(1) : item.getId()` has a type of `Integer` and no auto-unboxing needs to be done.

When you auto-unbox a `null` `Integer`, you get a `NullPointerException` (see [Autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)) and that is what you are experiencing.

To answer your question, this is correct behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`item` may not be `null`, but when you call `getId()`, that is returning `null`.  When you try to auto-unbox `null`, you get an NPE.

Comment: Are you sure? getId returns an Integer that happens to be null, so there should be no autoboxing. And if what you say is true then why does returning `new Integer(1)` make the NPE go away?

Comment: @Kevin With `new Integer(1)`, both the 2nd and 3rd operands are of type `Integer`, so that's the type of the conditional. With `1`, the type of the conditional expression is `int`, so `getId()`'s return value is unboxed to an `int`. (Check 15.25 of the JLS for the exact rules around this.)

Answer (score 3):

If you decompile the class file you will see clearly your NPE...

```
return Integer.valueOf(item != null ? item.getId().intValue() : 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type below is `Integer` -

```
public Integer f() {
    Item item = new Item();
    // this works:
    //return item == null ? new Integer(1) : item.getId();

    // NPE??
    return item == null ? 1 : item.getId();
}
```

And the result of the following -

```
item == null ? 1 : item.getId()
```

is `null` in your case.

So, JVM is throwing NPE because it is trying to autobox `null`.

Try -

```
new Integer(null); // and
Integer.valueOf(null);
```

both will throw NPE.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you are using conditional operator `?`. Line

`return item == null ? 1 : item.getId();`

is equivalent to

```
int result = item == null ? 1 : item.getId();
return result;
```

The result is int because of the first operand in your expression. This is the reason that your code works when you explicitly wrap 1 with Integer. In this case the compiler creates something like

```
Integer result = item == null ? new Integer(1) : item.getId();
return result;
```

So, NPE happens when attempting to "cast" item.getId() (that is null) to int.