# Unknown NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java

The following snippet uses simple Java code.

```
package pkg;

final public class Main
{
    final private class Demo
    {
        private Integer value = null;

        public Integer getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private Integer operations()
    {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        return demo==null?new Integer(1):demo.getValue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main main=new Main();
        System.out.println("Value = " + String.valueOf(main.operations()));
    }
}
```

The above code works as expected with no problem and displays `Value = null` on the console.

In the following `return` statement,

```
return demo==null?new Integer(1):demo.getValue();
```

since the object `demo` of type `Demo` is **not** `null`, the expression after `:` which is `demo.getValue()` is executed which invokes `getValue()` within the inner `Demo` class which returns `null` and finally, it is converted to String and displayed on the console.

But when I modify the `operations()` method something like the one shown below,

```
private Integer operations()
{
    Demo demo = new Demo();    
    return demo==null?1:demo.getValue();
}
```

it throws `NullPointerException`. How?

---

I mean when I use this `return` statement

```
return demo==null?new Integer(1):demo.getValue();
```

it works (doesn't throw `NullPointerException`)

and when I use the following **something similar** `return` statement

```
return demo==null?1:demo.getValue();
```

it causes `NullPointerException`. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811608/java-npe-in-ternary-operator-with-autoboxing

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange Java NullPointerException with autoboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265948/strange-java-nullpointerexception-with-autoboxing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This statement:

```
return demo==null?1:demo.getValue();
```

is actually being converted into something like this:

```
int tmp = demo == null ? 1 : demo.getValue().intValue();
return (Integer) tmp;
```

The type of the conditional expression is determined to be `int` (not `Integer`) based on the rules [laid out in the JLS, section 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), using [binary numeric promotion (5.6.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). The conversion from the null reference to `int` then triggers the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

```
return demo==null?new Integer(1):demo.getValue();
```

In this case the type of the expression is Integer, and null is a legal value.

```
return demo==null?1:demo.getValue();
```

In this case the type of the expression is int, so your Integer return value is automatically unboxed. And as it is null, it throws a NPE.