# is autoboxing the reason for NullPointerException?

Tags: java

```
public class NullTernary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        NullTernary obj= new NullTernary();
        obj.GetValue();
    }

    int GetValue()
     {
            return (true ? null : 0);
     }

}
```

Output of running `main` method of above class is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullTernary.GetValue(NullTernary.java:13)
    at NullTernary.main(NullTernary.java:8)
```

is Java auto boxing the reason for `NullPointerException` ( i.e. when function tries to convert `null` value to `Integer`) or some other explanation?

If auto boxing to Integer theory is correct, I was wondering why auto boxing be done when expected value in `int` and not `Integer` ?

Comment: Actually it's auto-unboxing causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: saw [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265948/nullpointerexception-with-autoboxing-in-ternary-expression) which explains it too.

Comment: `null` coul'd not be converted into `int` value. If you want to prevent the NPE, change signature from `int GetValue()` to `Integer GetValue()`.