# why it throw A NullPointerException occurs at runtime?

Tags: java

```
public class Boxer1 {
    Integer i;
    int x;

    public Boxer1(int y) {
        x = i + y;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Boxer1(new Integer(4));
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code, a `NullPointerException` occurs at line 5. What's happening?

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting the code in your question before posting. This looks horrible at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why does this code throw a NullPointerException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162658/why-does-this-code-throw-a-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 3):

```
x = i + y;
```

The problem is that `i` is an `Integer` object and initializes to null.

You can fix this issue by replacing:

```
Integer i;
```

With one of the following:

```
int i;
int i = 0;
Integer i = 0;
```

Comment: @user3690771 Welcome to SO! :) If this helps you, mark it as accepted to help future visitors to the site.

Comment: That is a questionable "fix".

Comment: This would hide the exception without really fixing the problem, which is, you are not initializing the variable.  Both `Integer i = 0;` and `int i=0;` would be preferable to a bare definition.

Comment: Given the "Boxer" class name I would assume OP's playing around with boxed primitives.

Answer (score 2):

Integer is an object, not a primitive type.  By default, objects are initialized to null.
A NullPointerException means you tried to "send a message" to an object that hasn't been initialized yet.

Try changing

```
Integer
```

to

```
int
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `Integer`, it initializes to *null* by default. This is because `Integer` is an object, not a primitive type like `int`. You get a `NullPointerException` when you try to do something with an object that is `null`, (hasn't been initialized). To fix this, you could use an `int`:

```
int i;
```

When you use an `int`, it automatically initializes to 0 if it isn't assigned any value. So, your end code should look something like this:

```
public class Boxer1 {
 int i; //<<< this line was changed from Integer i; to int i;
 int x;

 public Boxer1(int y) {
  x = i + y;
  System.out.println(x);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Boxer1(new Integer(4));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer is an object not primitive type.by default,it takes null and has yo be initialized.                                                      Make Integer I=0

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Boxer1 {
    Integer i;
    int x;
    public Boxer1(int y) {
        x=i+y;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Boxer1(new Integer(4));
     throw new NullPointerException(); 
    try{
        doBoxer1();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex){
        System.out.println("NPE encountered in body");
    } catch (Throwable ex){

    }

    }
}
```

Note : Integer i is declared but not initialized: it's a null pointer.